# How do I make php wait for curl to finish before continuing?

Tags: php, curl

It seems if I do something like

```
$file = fopen($filepath, "w");
$CR = curl_init();
curl_setopt($CR, CURLOPT_URL, $source_path);
curl_setopt($CR, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($CR, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($CR, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($CR, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($CR, CURLOPT_FILE, $file);
$result = curl_exec( $CR );
$error = curl_error( $CR );
print filesize($filepath);
```

I get a different result than if I just run

```
print filesize($filepath);
```

a second time.  My guess is that curl is still downloading when do a filesize().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that functions like filesize() cache their result, try adding a call to clearstatcache() above 'print filesize(...);'. Here is an example:

```
$file = '/tmp/test12345';
file_put_contents($file, 'hello');
echo filesize($file), "\n";
file_put_contents($file, 'hello world, this is a test');
echo filesize($file), "\n";
clearstatcache();
echo filesize($file), "\n";
```

See www.php.net/clearstatcache

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have the same problem. curl is supposed to be synchronous, but, depending on how you're using it, it's not synchronous.
If you call, after curl, a print, or echo, the content comes void. There's a strange delay.
But I'll try this approach -

```
print_r(curls_getinfo($CR));
```

Doing everything in one step may solve the problem.